# Casimir force between plate and sphere

Tags: quantum-optics, casimir-effect

In our quantum optics lecture we derived the formula for the [Casimir force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect) between two plates (or at least the force per unit surface, since for two infinite plates we would have an infinite force). It was then said, that in experiments one often uses [a sphere and a plate](http://www.google.com/search?q=Casimir+plate+sphere) to measure the force, where the small distance between the sphere and the plate is varied by a piezo.

I'm not particularly interested in how exactly the force is measured but rather how to theoretically calculate it in this case. Our professor said, the measured forces agree with the theory up to 1% so I guess, there is a way to calculate it.
Let's say I have a sphere of radius $R$ in a distance $d$ from a plate where $R\gg d$. How can I theoretically calculate the Casimir force between a plate and a sphere?